# How can I write an A to Z word index algorithm that converts subranges to index pairs?

Tags: php, algorithm, indexing

I have an a sorted list of names, from which I have created an array of sub-ranges:

List: **AAA**, AAAA, BA, BB, **BBCC**, **BBD**, CCC, DDD, **EE**, FFF, FFG,
      GG, **GGA**, **GGGB**, ...

Sub-Range: [AAA-BBCC], [BBD-EE], [FFF-GGA], [GGGB-...], ...

I then wrote a function to convert the sub-ranges to a set of minimum A to Z index pairs, such as you might find on a filing drawer label.

[A-B], [B-E], [F-G], [G-...], ...

But, my function incorrectly 'calculates' the wrong pair values, which should in this case be:

[A-BBC], [BBD-E]. [F-GGA], [GGG-...], ...

I'm working in PHP, in case the language function might help.

Wrong as it is, here is my code:

```
$indexCount = count( $tempData );

for( $i = 0; $i < $indexCount; ) {

    $lowValue  = $tempData[ $i ][ 'lowValue' ];
    $highValue = $tempData[ $i ][ 'highValue' ];

    // Find the minimum non-matching lowValue compared to the highValue ...

    if( !empty( $highValue ) ) {

        for( $j = strlen( $lowValue ) - 1; $j > 0; --$j ) {

            if( $lowValue !== $highValue ) {

                $lowValue = substr( $lowValue, 0, $j );

            }
            else {

                break;

            } // End of if( $lowValue !== $highValue ) ... else ...

        } // End of for( $j = strlen( $lowValue ) - 1; $j > 0; --$j ) ...

    }
    else {

        $lowValue = substr( $lowValue, 0, 1 );

    } // End of if( !empty( $highValue ) ) ...

    // Find the minimum non-matching highValue compared to the minimized lowValue ...

    if( !empty( $highValue ) ) {

        $highValue = substr( $highValue, 0, $j );

        // If after minimizing both values and the values are the same, then ...

        if( $lowValue === $highValue ) {

            //
            // Add back the next character from the original values to each
            // minimized value ...
            //

            $lowValue  = substr( $tempData[ $i ][ 'lowValue' ],  0, $j + 1 );
            $highValue = substr( $tempData[ $i ][ 'highValue' ], 0, $j + 1 );

        } // End of if( $lowValue === $highValue ) ...

    } // End of if( !empty( $highValue ) ) ...

    // Save the minimized values ...

    $tempData[ $i ][ 'lowShortValue'  ] = $lowValue;
    $tempData[ $i ][ 'highShortValue' ] = $highValue;

    //
    // Originally, my code stopped here, but then I realized that I also
    // needed to minimize the high value and next low value to bridge the
    // sub-ranges ...
    //

    $k = $i;

    if( ++$i < $indexCount ) {

        $lowValue  = $tempData[ $k ][ 'highValue' ];
        $highValue = $tempData[ $i ][ 'lowValue' ];

        // Find the minimum non-matching lowValue compared to the highValue ...

        for( $j = strlen( $lowValue ) - 1; $j > 0; --$j ) {

            if( $lowValue !== $highValue ) {

                $lowValue = substr( $lowValue, 0, $j );

            }
            else {

                break;

            } // End of if( $lowValue !== $highValue ) ... else ...

        } // End of for( $j = strlen( $lowValue ) - 1; $j > 0; --$j ) ...

        //
        // Find the minimum non-matching highValue compared to the
        // minimized lowValue ...
        //

        if( !empty( $highValue ) ) {

            $highValue = substr( $highValue, 0, $j );

            // If after minimizing both values and the values are the same, then ...

            if( $lowValue === $highValue ) {

                //
                // Add back the next character from the original values to each
                // minimized value ...
                //

                $lowValue  = substr( $tempData[ $k ][ 'highValue' ], 0, $j + 1 );
                $highValue = substr( $tempData[ $i ][ 'lowValue' ],  0, $j + 1 );

            } // End of if( $lowValue === $highValue ) ...

        } // End of if( !empty( $highValue ) ) ...

        // Save the minimized values ...

        $tempData[ $k ][ 'highValue' ] = $lowValue;
        $tempData[ $i ][ 'lowValue' ]  = $highValue;

    } // End of if( ++$i < $indexCount ) ...

} // End of for( $i = 0; $i < $indexCount; ++$i ).
```

Besides, not working, I have two additional issues with this code:

1) I store the lowShortValue and highShortValues into the $tempData array twice, overwriting the value that was 'calculated' for that index.

2) Should the array of sub-ranges be reverse scanned, so I can 'carry' the minimized value from one sub-range down to the one before, and skip the minimizing of the highValue in each pair?

Comment: Thanks  for the clarification. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a "good" algorithm, but it works and does have some optimized elements that reduce reminimizing of the values.

```
//
// Truncate the lowValue and highValue index values to produce a range of minimal index values.
//
// If the original values were:
//
//   ant - apple, bear - cab, cat - chimp, dog - fry, teller - total
//
// Then the range values would be reduced to:
//
//  an - ap, b - cat, cab - ch, d - f, te - to
//

if( ( $indexCount = count( $tempData ) ) > 0 ) {

    //
    // $indexCount = 5, meaning that there are five sub-ranges.
    //
    // Loop 1a: $i = 4, $j = 4, %k = 0, compare: teller & total           => te  - to
    // Loop 1b: $i = 4, $j = 3, %k = 1, compare: fry    & te     (bridge) => f   - te
    // Loop 2a: $i = 3, $j = 3, %k = 0, compare: dog    & f               => d   - f
    // Loop 2b: $i = 3, $j = 2, %k = 1, compare: chimp  & dog    (bridge) => ch  - d
    // Loop 3a: $i = 2, $j = 2, %k = 0, compare: ca     & ch              => ca  - ch <─────┐
    // Loop 3b: $i = 2, $j = 1, %k = 1, compare: cab    & cat    (bridge) => cab - cat, cat - ch
    // Loop 4a: $i = 1, $j = 1, %k = 0, compare: bear   & cab             => b   - cab
    // Loop 4b: $i = 1, $j = 0, %k = 1, compare: apple  & b      (bridge) => ap  - b
    // Loop 5a: $i = 0, $j = 0, %k = 0, compare: ant    & apple           => an  - ap
    //

    $retrim = true;

    // Process the sub-ranges from right (larger) to left (smaller) ...

    for( $i = $j = $indexCount - 1; $i >= 0; --$i ) {

        //
        // Loop part A - $i === $j
        //

        if( empty( $newLowValue ) ) {

            // Get the low value from sub-range's low value ...

            $newLowValue = $lowValue = $tempData[ $i ][ 'lowValue' ];

        } // End of if( empty( $newLowValue ) ) ...

        if( $retrim === true ) {

            // Get high value from the sub-range's high value ...

            $newHighValue = $highValue = $tempData[ $i ][ 'highValue' ];

        }
        else {

            // Get high value from the previous right (larger) sub-range's low value ...

            $newHighValue = $highValue = $newLowValue;

            // Get the low value from sub-range's low value ...

            $newLowValue = $lowValue = $tempData[ $i ][ 'lowValue' ];

        } // End of if( $retrim === true ) ... else ...

        // With in the sub-range, look for the first difference between the two strings ...

        $k = 1;
        $l = max( strlen( $newLowValue ), strlen( $newHighValue ) ) ;

        while( $k < $l ) {

            $newLowValue = mb_substr( $lowValue,  0, $k );

            if( $retrim === true ) {

                $newHighValue = mb_substr( $highValue, 0, $k );

            } // End of if( $retrim === true ) ...

            if( $newLowValue !== $newHighValue ) {

                break;

            } // End of if( $newLowValue !== $newHighValue ) ...

            ++$k;

        } // End of while( $k < $l ) ...

        // Save the trimmed high value ...

        $tempData[ $i ][ 'highShortValue' ] = $newHighValue;

        //
        // Loop part B - Bridge - $i === $j + 1
        //

        if( --$j < 0 ) {

            // No more sub-ranges, can't bridge, save the trimmed low value ...

            $tempData[ $i ][ 'lowShortValue' ] = $newLowValue;

        }
        else {

            // Bridge.

            $newHighValue = $highValue = $newLowValue;
            $newLowValue  = $lowValue  = $tempData[ $j ][ 'highValue' ];

            if( mb_substr( $newLowValue, 0, strlen( $newHighValue ) ) === $newHighValue ) {

                //
                // Too many characters were trimmed from the high value, re-trim the
                // previous-sub-range's un-trimmed lowValue ...
                //

                $retrim = true;

                $newHighValue = $highValue = $tempData[ $i ][ 'lowValue' ];

            }
            else {

                $retrim = false;

            } // End of if( mb_substr( $newLowValue, 0, strlen( $newHighValue ) ) ===
              //              $newHighValue ) ... else ...

            //
            // In the bridge between the $j and $i sub-ranges, look for the first difference
            // between the two strings ...
            //

            $k = 1;
            $l = max( strlen( $lowValue ), strlen( $highValue ) );

            while( $k < $l ) {

                $newLowValue = mb_substr( $lowValue, 0, $k );

                if( $retrim === true ) {

                    $newHighValue = mb_substr( $highValue, 0, $k );

                } // End of if( $retrim === true ) ...

                if( $newLowValue !== $newHighValue ) {

                    break;

                } // End of if( $newLowValue !== $newHighValue ) ...

                ++$k;

            } // End of while( $k < $l ) ...

            // Bridge, save the trimmed low value ...

            $tempData[ $i ][ 'lowShortValue' ] = $newHighValue;

            $retrim                            = false;

        } // End of if( --$j >= 0 ) ...

    } // End of for( $i = $indexCount - 1; $i >= 0; --$i ).

} // End of if( ( $indexCount = count( $tempData ) ) > 0 ) ...
```

As I suggested in the question, I changed the direction of scanning through the sub-ranges, from Left to Right (ascending order) to Right to Left (descending order).  While not necessary, it did make the process clearer to me  and allowed me to carry the minimized values between the two loop parts, and helped to eliminate storing the values twice for the same sub-range.

The another thing that I found was that I needed to change from **substr** to **mb_substr**.  It isn't clear from the data that I showed, but the side-effect of using **substr** was that sometimes the function returned the original un-truncated string, no matter the value of length parameter.  Additionally, the **if( retrim )** tests that were added to the code after the version in the original question, which were assigned **true** and **false** boolean values would fail and the code block inside the if-then statements would execute even when they should not.  I changed these to **if( retrim === true )** when I changed to the **mb_substr** function and the side-effects stopped occurring.